# Transforming a polynomial sum using a series expansion (BCH codes)

Tags: polynomials, summation, power-series, finite-fields

In my study of [BCH codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code#Forney_algorithm) I've come across the following equation (the "key equation"):

$$
\Omega(x) \equiv \Lambda(x)S(x) \mod x^{n-k} \tag{1}
$$

Where the two terms on the right are defined by:

$$
\Lambda(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{\nu}(1-X_k x) \\
S(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-k-1} \left( x^j \sum_{k=1}^{\nu} Y_k X_k^{c+j} \right)
$$

(And $2\nu<n-k$.)  In most of the papers I've read, it is stated with no explanation that $\Omega(x)$ is therefore equal to:

$$
\Omega(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\nu}\left( X_i^c Y_i \prod_{\substack{k=1 \\ k\ne i}}^{\nu}(1-X_k x)\right) \tag{2}
$$

(Or vice-versa, $(2)$ is treated as the definition, and it is then stated that $(1)$ must be true.)  The $X_k$, and $Y_k$, and $x$ are members of a finite field, if it makes a difference.

My question is **how can we show this to be true?**

So far my best try has been to try factoring the product out of the summation on the left, and changing the order of the summations on the right:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}\left( X_i^c Y_i \prod_{\substack{k=1 \\ k\ne i}}^{\nu}(1-X_k x)\right) &\equiv \left[\prod_{k=1}^{\nu}(1-X_k x)\right]\left[ \sum_{j=0}^{n-k-1} \left( x^j \sum_{k=1}^{\nu} Y_k X_k^{c+j} \right)\right] \\
\left[\prod_{k=1}^{\nu}(1-X_k x)\right]\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\nu} \frac{Y_k X_k^c}{1-X_k x} \right] &\equiv \left[\prod_{k=1}^{\nu}(1-X_k x)\right]\left[ \sum_{k=1}^{\nu} Y_k X_k^c\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-k-1} (X_k x)^j \right)\right]
\end{align}
$$

(Remember this is taken $\text{mod}~x^{n-k}$.)

This looks promising, since the series expansion of $(1-x)^{-1}$ is $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i$.  Intuitively I feel like I should be able to replace $(1-X_k x)^{-1}$ with an infinite sum, then somehow truncate that sum due to the $\text{mod}~x^{n-k}$.  I'm stuck on three points:

1. Can I justify introducing a division?  I know it has to cancel with one of the product terms, but it makes me uneasy.  If I use the series expansion I get an infinite number of terms in the polynomial, how can this be equal to the original expression which clearly has a finite degree?
2. The sum is getting "mixed" with the product in a polynomial multiplication, so the terms in this sum are going to get spread out over different powers of $x$; how can I know where to truncate the series?
3. Usually if I truncate a series expansion, I get an approximation to the original function.  Why doesn't it introduce error in this case?